# DataTables 1.10 - Not Showing Results

Tags: jquery, html, datatables, datatables-1.10

This is my setup.

**Javascript/jQuery:**

```
$('#list').dataTable({
    paging: false,
    serverSide: true,
    ajax: {
        url: "/search/",
        data: function (d) {
            return $.extend({}, d, {
                lid: Label.selectedId
            });
        }
    }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<table id="list" class="table table-striped" width="100%">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>URL</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

**JSON Response**

```
{"data": [["Test", "", "", ""]], "recordsTotal": 1, "draw": 1, "recordsFiltered": 1}
```

It is getting called manually by doing this:

```
$('#list').DataTable().ajax.reload();
```

But the table does not change. I've done this many times with DataTables 1.9 without a hitch -- any ideas?

---

**UPDATE**

I discovered if I turn off `serverSide`, it works.

Comment: No, nothing showing in the console.

Comment: One thing I'd try is setting 'processing': true, so that you can tell if datatables is thinking.

Comment: I tried that earlier, and it got stuck there... still with no console output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the problem. It was with the `draw` in the JSON response. It was always 1.

If you use `serverSide: true`, that means it is going to send `draw` as a variable, and it must be returned.

More information here:
http://datatables.net/manual/server-side

Comment: Thank you!!! This was driving me crazy. Worked like a charm after returning the draw variable back from server.