# dataTables 1.10.1 - no json data displayed

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, datatables

Let's keep it short.
I have simple dataTables (**1.10.1**) implementation to make but with code below nothing shows up. Not even a sigle error.

For testing purposes data is loaded from the local server. It's a valid json and and it opens in a browser. Using e.g. Firebug in firefox I can see data loading in a background but I guess data fields from json are not properly accessed and that may be the source of the problem.

Json is handled by the server properly. In the example below it is a flat file but I'm looking for a solution to handle either a flat file or dynamic output from server e.g. output from webapi.

I have read http://datatables.net/examples/ajax/deep.html and many other sources like [DataTables 1.10 - Not Showing Results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24171141/datatables-1-10-not-showing-results) but I didn't find any clues.

Can you please take a look and help me with this one? ..and I'm really sorry for bothering if the solution is obvious :(
Thanks for understanding.

**Scripts + css in page header:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.1/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.1/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```

**JSON data (output from `http://server/input_data.json`):**

```
{
    "servicestatuslist": {
        "servicestatus": [
            {
                "service_id": "Tiger Nixon",
                "host_name": "System Architect",
                "host_address": "$320,800",
                "display_name": "2011/04/25",
                "status_text": "Edinburgh",
                "last_check" : "5421"
            },
            {
                "service_id": "Garrett Winters",
                "host_name": "Accountant",
                "host_address": "$170,750",
                "display_name": "2011/07/25",
                "status_text": "Tokyo",
                "last_check" : "8422"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**JavaScript on the page:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').dataTable({
            processing: true,
            ajax: 'http://server/input_data.json',
            columns: [
                { data: 'servicestatus.service_id' },
                { data: 'servicestatus.host_name' },
                { data: 'servicestatus.host_address' },
                { data: 'servicestatus.display_name' },
                { data: 'servicestatus.status_text' },
                { data: 'servicestatus.last_check' }
            ]
        });
    });
</script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>id</th>
            <th>hostname</th>
            <th>address</th>
            <th>service</th>
            <th>message</th>
            <th>time</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer myself. It is indeed very simple but although the json input is nested, the starting point for the solution was the "Flat array data source".

There (http://datatables.net/examples/ajax/custom_data_flat.html) is a caption about data default parameter name, which (as it turns out) can easily be changed using dataSrc. The solution to my problem was setting ajax as follows:

```
ajax: { 
url: 'http://server/input_data.json',
dataSrc: 'servicestatuslist.servicestatus'
}
```

and call column data like

```
{ data: 'service_id' }
```